# How to return a tuple, multiple value from a function?

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples

I want for these function to return a tuple with the sorted list, the number of total changes and comparisons done.

```
def selection_sort(lst):

    k=0
    for i in range(len(lst)):             
        minPos = 1            
        counter_comp = 1            
        for j in range( i + 1, len (lst)):    
            if lst[j] < lst[minPos]:
                minPos = j
            counter_comp+=1                         
        temp =lst[minPos]
        lst[minPos] = lst[i]
        lst[i] = temp    
        k=k+1                
    return (lst, k, counter_comp)    

exemplo=[4,9,3,7]    
selection_sort(example)    
print (example)

# I already tried to do print and only returns a list. doesn't return tuple.
```

Comment: You never print the result of the function call: `print(selection_sort(example))`.

Comment: or `result = selection_sort(example)` `print(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're printing the example and not the result itself. Change this to `print(selection_sort(example))`

Comment: Please don't pass `bereal`'s comment off as your own answer.